# How do I include ':Send' in the type signature?

Tags: rust

I'm chaining and flatmapping some iterators and procs together in an attempt to get make some code execute lazily. Unfortunately I'm getting an error I can't overcome.

The error refers to the return type and says 'expected no bounds but found `Send`'. I've never had to include 'Send' in the return type description before and rustc won't parse e.g. collections::vec::MoveItems:Send>. How should I include Send in the type signature?
(Or should I be doing something else?)

> ../racer/nameres.rs:623:12: 623:14 error: mismatched types: expected `core::iter::Chain<core::iter::Chain<core::iter::Chain<core::iter::Chain<core::iter::FlatMap<'static,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,core::iter::FlatMap<'static,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>>,core::iter::FlatMap<'static,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>>,core::iter::FlatMap<'static,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>>,core::iter::FlatMap<'static,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>>` but found `core::iter::Chain<core::iter::Chain<core::iter::Chain<core::iter::Chain<core::iter::FlatMap<'_,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,core::iter::FlatMap<'_,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>>,core::iter::FlatMap<'_,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>>,core::iter::FlatMap<'_,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>>,core::iter::FlatMap<'_,proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>:Send,core::option::Item<proc() -> collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>:Send>,collections::vec::MoveItems<racer::Match>>>` (expected no bounds but found `Send`)

Answer (score 0):

That’s a rather ugly case, and rather misleading. It should be fixed and made consistent.

What it is showing as `proc() -> T:Send` must be written `proc():Send -> T`.